# Using Reflection to Prevent a Secret From Being Logged

Tags: go

Say we have a type to encapsulate sensitive information, which can only be accessed by calling its `SecretValue` method:

```
type Secret struct {
    secret string
}

func (s *Secret) SecretValue() string {
    return s.secret
}
```

We wish to prevent the sensitive info `secret` from leaking into logs.  Specifically, we want to ensure that the `string` returned by `SecretValue()` is never later passed as an argument to any method that can write to stdout, stderr, or a file -- that is, methods like `fmt.Printf`, `fmt.Println`, `fmt.Errorf`, etc.

1. Is it possible, either by static analysis of the code, or by using reflection at runtime, to enforce such a policy?  If so, how, at a high-level, would this be achieved?
2. Is it even possible to enumerate "all methods in the standard library that can possible write to stdout, stderr, or a file"?  If so, how?

Comment: If you don't want to to be automatically printed by most everything, don't make the type a `fmt.Stringer`. The answer to both 1 and 2 is No.

Comment: @JimB The value still needs to be accessible, I just want to prevent its being logged

Comment: You could still access it via any other method name. A `fmt.Stringer` is automatically called in so many places, making a "secret stringer" is just going to be a liability (unless of course, `String()` returned something obfuscated).

Comment: Fair enough.  Same question then for a method named `SecretValue()`

Comment: I edited the question to clarify

Comment: Nothing in the stdlib automatically calls `SecretValue` methods, so what is there to prevent?

Comment: Some of our own code calls it and passes the returned value to, say, `fmt.Println`

Comment: Oh, you want to see where the actual string is passed, not the Secret value itself. You probably need to do that heuristically, and I would adapt the `vet` tool code if I were to attempt this, but that's far too broad for an answer here. Realistically, most would probably just make this mandatory in code review.

Comment: Correct.  Currently we do this in code review, but that’s not foolproof and since it’s security critical, we’d like to enforce it programmatically, if possible

Comment: It seems like whatever packages are responsible for consuming and using secrets should provide functions that accept secrets of type `interface{ SecretValue() string }`; anything _not_ in that package would then have no business directly calling a method named `SecretValue()`, and you could probably set up a custom static analysis tool to catch instructions that would do it outside of the sanctioned packages/contexts. You could refer to the gosec project for some [examples](https://github.com/securego/gosec/blob/master/rules/blacklist.go) of using `go/ast` for this.

Comment: @JesseAmano That's a good suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Implementing a Stringer interface on the Secret, might actually be a good idea, provided your String() returns obfuscated value.